# Pandas.DataFrame.query Series.str.startswith Tuple returns Empty

Tags: python, pandas

In the following example, the final DataFrame returns empty -- what am I missing?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo':['010','020','030','040','050','060','070','080','090',None],
    'bar':['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii','jjj']
})
df1 = df[df.foo.str.startswith('01',na=False)]
df2 = df[df.foo.str.startswith(('01','03'),na=False)]
df3 = df.query("foo.str.startswith('01',na=False)")
df4 = df.query("foo.str.startswith(('01','03'),na=False)")
```

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: This should work: `df.query("foo.str.startswith(tuple(('01','03')),na=False)")`. Guess it is not recognizing the fact that you are passing a tuple. Cf. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69903522/df-query-not-working-when-values-are-tuples-in-pandas-dataframe). Though, I'm not able to get the `variable` option there to work for your example.

Comment: @ouroboros1 I guess in most recent version of pandas the tuple trick will not work.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: you're right, it depends on the version. Snippet above is throwing an error in 1.5.3 (was working in 1.4.4). But then, `df.query("foo.str.startswith(('01','03'),na=False)")` also throws the same error in 1.5.3: `TypeError: expected a string or tuple, not list`, so assuming the OP is not using recent.

Comment: @ouroboros1 Thanks for testing against different versions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently using a `@` resolves this issue with a tuple defined before hand like:

```
t = ('01', '03')

df.query("foo.str.startswith(@t, na=False)")
```

output:

```
    foo bar
0   010 aaa
2   030 ccc
```

From [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) doc:

> Parameters

> exprstr
>
> ```
>     The query string to evaluate.
>
>     You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing 
>     them with an ‘@’ character like @a + b.
> ```

Comment: I think this is the correct way to go

Comment: This does indeed work -- thank you!  I'd be curious to understand why the inline query string isn't being interpreted correct...

Comment: @jbeckom From the error `TypeError: expected a string or tuple, not list` it seems the parser is not able to parse it into a tuple but rather list. Seems like a bug in the query parser?